# Change the color of an element on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, css

i want to make the nav color change every time there's a mouseenter until it reaches 4 different colors. So far im able to change only the background color of the first nav element, even when usingvquerySelectorAll().

```
This is the CSS
nav {
z-index: 1;
position: fixed;
width: 52px;
height: 299px;
font-family: 'News Cycle';
font-style: bold;
font-weight:600;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 33px;
text-align: center;

color: #000000;

}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    
}

nav a {
    color: rgba(5, 5, 5);
    text-decoration: none;
}


and this is the javascript i have



const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
let currentIndex = 0;
const myElement = document.getElementById('info');

myElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  myElement.style.color = colors[currentIndex];
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.length;
});
```

I want the code to select the text color of ALL the nav elements but only works for backgroundColor for the first nav, if that makes sense

Comment: Can you please add the HTML code as well

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your HTML. If your element is a container div wrapping the other elements you mentioned, you could try with setting the childElements color explicit to inherit.
Or in your mouseover you can try changing the color for each of the childElements.
(Get the collection by className or tag - whatever works for you)